# File size on disk with WebResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to retreive file size on disk using webresponse?
if not, how can i retreive the file size?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(finalUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 24;

//request.Method = "HEAD";
var contentType = string.Empty;

using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
{
    contentType = webResponse.ContentType;
    using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
            Int32 bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            documentFile.Data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the total number of bytes you intend to download. The downloaded data might never be stored on a disk on either side so talking about "file size on disk" is a rather confusing term in this context.

Comment: `int byteCount = file.ContentLength;` and the same can be converted to Kb or KB as per need

Comment: Can you elaborate on the scenario - are you trying to get hold of a file, that has been submitted to an endpoint - or what are you trying to do here?

Comment: `documentFile` is a file you plan to save, I think? So you can get the number of bytes already. This should be a pretty good indicate of the size on disk. If that's not accurate enough, save it, and then check its size.

Comment: yes documentFile is my stored file but it doesnt seems to be the same as filesize on disk. 12mb when i download the file compare to 2855 bytes with ContentLength or Length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it is the only way to get the file size information from the site before downloading the file is reading `ContentLength` header and there is no guarantee that server provide it.

```
var fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;
```

or after download the file, you can get the length of the stream to retrieve size;

```
var fileSize = memoryStream.Length;
```

Comment: I tried that but it isn't the same as the filesize on disk. I am missing something?

Comment: Tried which one ? Also, where do you save the file to disk ?

Comment: both webResponse.ContentLength and memoryStream.Length returns the size, but not the actual size on disk. The file is save through DocumentFile on the server.